# Text blocks over images

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using the instafeed library to get instagram images to my website, now with the instafeed library its really easy to get the caption of the images.

Now my problem is that i would like to have the caption text on the bottom of every image.

But since this is dynamically created I cant manipulate the outputted html, so I wonder if its possible with CSS to put the image text on bottom of every image.

HTML

```
<div id="instafeed">
<img src="http://distilleryimage9.s3.amazonaws.com/3a81fe1e206d11e38bc322000a9d0dcb_7.jpg">
<div class="caption">#windows #shadows #art #bw #abstract #overlap</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.caption {
    background-color:#ccc;
    }

img {
width: 33.33%;
float: left;

 }
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d3cpf/)

Comment: If you have multiple pictures what does the markup look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the instafeed library, you have the ability to specify the template in a way that works for your layout.

For instance, changing the template to this:

```
var feed = new Instafeed({
    get: 'tagged',
    tagName: 'overlap',
    clientId: 'baee48560b984845974f6b85a07bf7d9',
    sortBy: 'random',
    links: false,
    resolution: 'standard_resolution',
    template: '<div class="wrap"><img src="{{image}}"/><div class="caption">{{caption}}</div></div>'
});
```

gives you a wrapping div around your image and caption.

You can than define your styles to get the effect you want:

<kbd>[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidcl64/d3cpf/5/)</kbd>  or <kbd>[Demo txt on img](http://jsfiddle.net/davidcl64/d3cpf/6/)</kbd>

Comment: See the second example I just posted.

Comment: Thank you!! this works like a charm. right out of the box.
thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

```
img {
clear:both;
display:block;
}
```

This will make the image "push" other floating elements around it.

#### [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/raam86/XJvnN/1/)

Comment: Yes, but I want the images to float left of each other.

Comment: Put the images inside a container and apply the `clear` css to that. 
You can still float the containers